# Uncheck bootstrap radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I'm trying to uncheck a radio button wrapped with a label in a button group like this:

```
<div>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
              <input type="radio" name="radio1" class="radio1" />
    Radio1
            </label>
</div>
<div>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
              <input type="radio" name="radio2" class="radio2" />
    Radio2
            </label>
</div>
$('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
      // Check if another option was previously checked
      if ($(this).parent().parent().find(':radio:checked').length == 1) {
        inner_input = $(this).find('input');
        if (inner_input.prop('checked')) {
          e.stopImmediatePropagation();
          e.preventDefault();
          inner_input.prop('checked', false);
          $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
});
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work and the label is still active even after the second click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why this happens?

Let's first see what are `click`, `mouseup` and `mousedown` events :

**mousedown**

> Fires when the user depresses the mouse button.

**mouseup**

> Fires when the user releases the mouse button.

**click**

> Fires when a mousedown and mouseup event occur on the same element.
>   Fires when the user activates the element that has the keyboard focus
>   (usually by pressing Enter or the space bar).

So When using `click` event, the radio button is checked, it means that `radio.is(':checked')` will always return `true` unless you disable default behavior. So you can do what you want in 2 ways :

**1-** With `Mouseup` event, in this case you can determine the state of radio button wether it's checked or not.But in this way you need one little extra code to disable the default behvaior of `click` event

```
$('label').on('mouseup', function(e){
    var radio = $(this).find('input[type=radio]');

  if( radio.is(':checked') ){
    radio.prop('checked', false);

  } else {
    radio.prop('checked', true);

  }

});

// Disable default behavior
$('label').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tv3gzeyw/)**

**And 2** , You can wrap it all together, disable `click`'s default behavior and do the rest in one event:

```
$('label').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var radio = $(this).find('input[type=radio]');

    if (radio.is(':checked')) {
        radio.prop('checked', false);

    } else {
        radio.prop('checked', true);

    }
});
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e3rha1cw/)**

I did answer this question using 2 different events with a purpose, sometimes in more complex problems you may be forced to use the `mouseup` event instead of `click`

Comment: I have prevented the default behavior haven’t I ?

Comment: @Lior Yes, but , `click` is not the proper event to uncheck radio buttons , isn't this what you want?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted. Can you tell me why it doesn't work with 'click'? Isn't mouseup and click have the same effect?

Comment: @Lior I updated the answer explaining why this happens

Answer (score 3):

The solution in current answer works well for radio inputs. But it didn't work for button groups. To save other searchers of trouble, following code might be helpful:

```js
$('label').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var radio = $(this).find('input[type=radio]');

  if (radio.is(':checked')) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    radio.prop('checked', false);
  } else {
    radio.prop('checked', true);

  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary active">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked>
        option 1
    </label>
  <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off">
        option 2
    </label>
  <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off">
        option 3
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked for me, it's just missing a line under `radio.prop('checked', true);` to add the .active class to the label